# SSIS balanced data distributor transformation occurs data loss

Tags: ssis, bdd

I use SSIS balanced data distributor transformation in SQL Server 2014 to insert data. It works when running in my local computer. When I deployed to another environment and I also install balanced data distributor transformation component, a strange thing happened. When I was executing the package having BDD, it displayed 'success', but the data did not insert to destination table.

Comment: How did you execute the package?

Comment: Use SQL Agent Job to run the package. Originally I used 4 BDDs running in the package, but it run OK after I change to 2 BDDs. That is really strange. The core of the machine is at least 8.

Comment: Check your package and make sure it will raise an error if it encounters one.   Check the `FailPackageOnError` properties on all the objects in the package.   Maybe it is hitting an error but not raising it to the job, so the job reports success.